# Why is my guitar coming out with a weird, distorted sound through my audio interface?

Tags: electric-guitar, ableton-live, homerecording

So i just bought / upgraded some of my gear to a Komplete Kontrol A49 and a Focusrite Scarlett 6i6. Downloaded my free Ableton Lite and plugged in my guitar to the no 1 instrument input on my Scarlett. And whilst I get a clean and nice sound through my headphones, when I record on Ableton via a audio track, I’m getting this weird distorted and buzzing sound on top of my clean guitar sound. Does anyone here know what’s going in? It’s kind of frustrating and depressing after saving for 1 year to get that equipment and have it fail on me. Would truly appreciate any help here l.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the buffer size settings in the audio driver? If it's set too low, you could get constant drop-outs that sound like a harsh loud irregular crackling sound mixed with the actual sound.

Comment: My first guess is "ground loop" - yes, those can occur with USB connections as well. But you should try to isolate the problem. Do you get the same sounds if the guitar is not plugged in? If it is plugged in, but you're not playing? Does adjusting the recording levels do anything? Have you tried other recording software, like Audacity? Etc. etc.

Comment: does it occur on other recording software too?

Comment: It's more about your PC performance and Audio Settings than your equipments. Just don't get frustrated. I've been in there, I bought a Samson Microphone after a really long time trying to convince my Parents into buying it. I started recording one day and the recording was all messy. I could here static noise over recording. Turned out my PC was not able to support the audio settings I've set. I suggest that you learn some of the basics of Audio settings and then go back to Ableton and tweak them: https://youtu.be/boPEO2auJj4?t=485

Comment: Also (I'm trying to edit my earlier comment but idk why I'm not able to) You might wanna check if the recording is Clipping (You are recording louder than maximum loudness supported in Audio Recording by Computers) [if you've watched the above Video I've linked then here: You are recording more than Float Value of 1 and Computers don't take values beyond 1 and will take any value beyond 1 to be 1 itself]

Answer (score 1):

Check the gain halos on the Scarlett. If they're red all the time, then you're clipping. Try pushing the Instrument button to adjust the levels if turning the gain knob all the way down doesn't work.

Check the levels on Ableton. Are your signals all pointy, or do they have plateaus? If your peaks are flat, then you're clipping your signal. Turn down the input levels in Ableton.

Check your settings on Ableton. You may be sampling at too high a rate for your computer or your buffer size might be too low. Remove all your VSTs in Ableton.